# Firefox 13 always saves .jar files with the .txt extension

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am downloading .jar file from a website, and it always adds .txt extension to the end of the file. I have no doubt that this is probably something wrong with how the website is passing the data to the browser. IE and Chrome do not have this issue. Is there anyway I can get Firefox to stop adding .txt to the end of the file via a config/options or extension change?

My OS: Windows 7

Browser: Firefox 13.0.1

**UPDATE**

Looking at it further the .jar file is being served using http header

Content-Type: text/plain

Is there anyway to get Firefox to ignore this while right clicking save/as?

Comment: Do you have an example page so that we can replicate the problem?

Comment: unfortunately no its an intranet site that is causing me the problem, I did some more research into the issue and it looks like its being caused by the content-type.

Comment: Select Options from the Tool menu, switch to the Applications tab and search for text and under Action pick Use Other... and then change the application to Java(TM) Platform SE Binary. This will probably mess things up when you actually want to download a text file, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a firefox addon that allows you to force the content type for particular URLs:

> [Force Content-Type](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/force-content-type/)
>
> An extension to force the Content-Type of URLs.
>
> It's useful to avoid the "tag soup" when you are developing a XHTML
> webpage and want Firefox to use its internal XML parser. If the
> webserver is not correctly configured, it will serve the page with a
> "text/html" Content-Type (a tag soup), instead of sending it as
> "application/xhtml+xml", and therefore avoiding Firefox to treat the
> page as pure XML.
>
> "Force Content-Type" allows you to define the Content-Type of some
> URLs (using Regular Expressions), overriding the webserver's incorrect
> Content-Type.

I would expect you to be able to use this to override your content-type from within Firefox.

The best way though is to get your webmaster to fix the content-type reported by the server for `.jar` files.

Comment: Funny you should mention that I was configuring it just as you posted this to test it :D, but yep it worked, I used Old Content Type text/plain and made it New Content-Type application/zip and it worked great. If anyone else is having the problem try using these new settings.